# RoR Error trying to run task: `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm having a problem whenever I try to run a Rake task that deletes certain records from the database older than 5 days, I just wanted to test it out first so I used just 1 day instead, anyway, after I execute `rails s RAILS_ENV=production rake delete:delete_5_old_days` I get that error: `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/rake`

This is the whole traceback

```
/home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/rake (LoadError)
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/RubymineProjects/adopt_bronze/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/RubymineProjects/adopt_bronze/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/RubymineProjects/adopt_bronze/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/RubymineProjects/adopt_bronze/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/RubymineProjects/adopt_bronze/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

And the task that I'm trying to execute is this:

```
namespace :delete do
  desc 'Delete records older than 5 days'
  task delete_5_days_old: :environment do
    Post.where(['created_at < ?, 1_day_ago']).each do |post|
      post.destroy
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you trying to run your rails server and the rake command in one shot? Did you try running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake delete:delete_5_old_days`?

Comment: This is not related to your error but your activerecord query is incorrect. It should be `Post.where(['created_at < ?', 1.day.ago])`

Comment: @archana Oh, sorry for the typo and yes, I was trying to do that. Tried your suggestion but it gave the same error, tried running just `bundle exec rake delete:delete_5_old_days_old` same error.

Comment: Can you stop spring `spring stop` and then run your rake?

Comment: @archana spring was not running.

Comment: @archana well, honestly I don't know what just happened but I just relaunched the console, did `bundle exec rake delete:delete_5_old_days` and it worked this time... I had relaunched the console already just _to be sure_ but it's working now :-)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.